# IBM Connections Service URL for Activity Stream

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am using the Social Business Toolkit (SBT) with the Extension Library.

Using the IBM documentation, I am struggling to find the service URL to get the updates from the activity stream (like what you see in the home page).

I am expecting to be able to do this but rather than get the users entries, get all entries that have been posted on their board/other users updates

```
new sbt.ConnectionsService("/profiles/atom/mv/theboard/entry/status.do?email=" +userBean.email);
```

Does anybody know it?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to greenhouse? If so this may be related to you. http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=1B07B7784D3C19AA86257B10008171A3

Comment: No, I am using an internal test environment. The code snippet included works, but returns all the users posts to the connections environment.

What I am wanting is the same as the discover part of the connections home page updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt.ConnectionsService is part of com.ibm.xsp.extlibx. That is different from the Social Business Toolkit SDK.

In order to read the entries from the activity stream using the SDK you can simply call ActivityStreamService.getAllUpdatesStream() or getActivityStreamEntries(String user, String group, String app, Map params) if you want to filter it.

See http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-entry-in-activity-stream-from-xpages-via-the-social-sdk-and-oauth2

Comment: Ah OK, so how would you do it from the extlib? I thought sbt.ConnectionsService was part of the SDK.

Comment: See ActivityStream.nsf http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/release.xsp?documentId=CC8F5413310C61E386257AD10026318D&action=openDocument